# How do I sort values in a shiny app dropdown menu

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

This is the code I am currently working with:

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)

# Create the data table
dt <- data.table(
  name = c("")
)

# Define the Shiny app UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("
      .wrapper {
        max-width: 1300px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
      }
      @media (min-width: 1300px) {
        .wrapper {
          margin-left: auto;
          margin-right: auto;
        }
      }
    "))
  ),
  # Wrap the contents of the page in a div with the wrapper class
  div(class = "wrapper",
      # Add a file input button
      fileInput("file", "Upload CSV file"),
      # Add a sidebar layout
      sidebarLayout(
        # Add a sidebar panel
        sidebarPanel(
          # Add checkboxes for each column in the data table
          checkboxGroupInput("columns", "Columns:", names(dt), selected = NULL),
          # Add a dropdown menu for the unique values of each selected column
          uiOutput("values")
        ),
        # Add a main panel
        mainPanel(
          # Add a data table to the main panel
          DT::dataTableOutput("table")
        )
      )
  )
)


# Define the Shiny app server logic
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Read the CSV file and replace the existing data in dt
  observeEvent(input$file, {
    if (is.null(input$file)) return()
    dt <<- fread(input$file$datapath)
    # Update the checkboxGroupInput with the names of the new data in dt
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "columns", choices = names(dt), selected = names(dt)[1])
  })
  
  # Create a reactive expression for the unique values of the selected columns
  values <- reactive({
    lapply(input$columns, function(x) {
      selectInput(x, x, c("All", unique(dt[, x, with = FALSE])), selected = "All")
    })
  })
  
  # Render the dropdown menus
  output$values <- renderUI({
    tagList(values())
  })
  
  # Create a reactive expression for the subset of the data table
  subset <- reactive({
    filters <- lapply(input$columns, function(x) {
      if (input[[x]] == "All") {
        TRUE
      } else {
        dt[[x]] %in% input[[x]]
      }
    })
    dt[Reduce(`&`, filters), ]
  })
  
  # Render the data table
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    subset()
  }, options = list(pageLength = 100))  # set pageLength = 100 to show 100 entries by default
  
}

# Run the Shiny app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The idea is that when new data is uploaded via a browse button prompt, radio buttons appear to select columns, and for the columns selected, dropdown menus are dynamically created that subset displayed data according to the unique values.

I want to modify the code so that the unique values in the dropdown menus are sorted, yet I can't for the life of me figure out how to modify the code without creating errors in reading the data.

Comment: Why doesn’t `sort(unique(dt[, x, with = FALSE])))` do what you want?

Comment: It produces an error below the radio buttons saying "undefined columns selected". For some reason when new data is loaded, the dropdown menus aren't reading the new data. No dropdown menus appear and the error appears in their place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed this line of code:

```
selectInput(x, x, c("All", unique(dt[, x, with = FALSE])), selected = "All")
```

to this:

```
selectInput(x, x, c("All", unique(dt[order(dt[, x, with = FALSE]), x, with = FALSE])), selected = "All")
```

The sort() function kept producing errors, but order() worked.